# Minimal LateX installation needed for a simple document

Tags: pdftex

I want to create a simple one page PDF document with some figures (png) plus some text (no maths) and would like to avoid installing the full 2GB MikTex for that. Is there some minimal small sized teX package designed for such small projects?
Thanks,

Comment: Related: [Minimal LaTeX installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17514/5764)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [What is the minimum distribution for LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4977/5764)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install a full distribution and you're only planning for small projects it would be better to use an online service to produce your (La)TeX documents. This leaves the onus on the service provider to keep up-to-date on the distribution, but in many cases also allows you to upload custom document classes or style files, including images.

There are a number of options available, as documented in [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3/5764).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea, I should have mentioned that I want to have it done on my computer (mac os)